# How to comment/edit multiple lines in vim/vi by using disjoint lines numbers

Tags: bash, vim

Say I have 10 lines:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
line 10
```

How do I comment out lines 1, 5 and 9 in vim?
I know how to comment out lines sequentially with :1,9s/^/# but what if I want to edit multiple separate line numbers?

```
# line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
# line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
# line 9
line 10
```

Comment: I don't think there is a single command that can do it.

Comment: You can do by using: `:g/^line [159]$/ s/^/#/`